# Interpolation Inequality (Sobolev embedding)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a $C^1$ domain, for any $\epsilon>0, 0<|\alpha|<k$, there exists a $C_\epsilon$ such that $$||D^\alpha u||_{L^p}\leq \epsilon||u||_{W^{k,p}}+C_\epsilon||u||_{L^p}$$
for all $u\in W^{k,p}$.

I was trying to prove it by contradiction.

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists u_n \in W^{k,p}$ such that $||D^\alpha u_n||_{L^p}>\epsilon||u_n||_{W^{k,p}}+n||u_n||_{L^p}$.

Anyone could give me a hint about using Sobolev compactness embedding?

I was trying to use the $W^{k,p}\subset \subset L^p$. However, I do not how to show that the sequence is bounded in $sup$.

By taking normalisation, $v_n=\frac{u_n}{||u_n||_{W^{k,p}}}$, we would have
$$\frac{1}{||u_n||_{W^{k,p}}}||D^\alpha u_n||_{L^p}>\epsilon+\frac{n}{||u_n||_{W^{k,p}}}||u_n||_{L^p}$$

Comment: By scaling the $u_n$, you can assume WLOG that they are all of $W^{k,p}$ norm $1$, because if there is a counterexample $u_n$ to the bound, then scaling that counterexample to be of norm $1$ by taking $\frac{u_n}{\|u_n\|_{W^{k,p}}}$ also produces a counterexample, so you could used the scaled function anyway. Now, you have a bounded sequence and can try to use the compact inclusion. Actually, this "norm one" assumption is quite a common one, when using compact inclusions.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to normalise $u_n$ to 1. But I still don't have the term bounded by the constant. So I can not extract subsequence.

Comment: Why can't you extract the subsequence? If $u_n$ is a bounded sequence in $W^{k,p}$ then it has a convergent subsequence in $L^p$, by the compact inclusion. By what I said earlier, the normalization makes $u_n$ bounded.

Comment: But I told you that we can WLOG that $\|u_n\|_{W^{k,p}} = 1$ for *all* $n$ by normalizing each of them. Then $\sup_n \|u_n\|_{W^{k,p}} = 1 <\infty$. If each of them has norm $1$, obviously the one having the largest norm has norm $1$.

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Comment: Great. Once you go along the proof assuming  the existence of the convergent subsequence, you still have a *little* more work to do. If you do that, put up an answer, else I will put it up if you want me to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113319/discussion-between-000000000-and-teresa-lisbon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the embedding $W^{k,p} \subset \subset L^p$ being compact is not good enough. We need something slightly stronger : for $0<|\alpha| < k$ the embedding $W^{k,p} \subset \subset W^{|\alpha|,p}$ is compact as well.

Once you have (following normalization) $\|u_n\|_{W^{k,p}} = 1$ for all $n$, the sequence $u_n$ is bounded in $W^{k,p}$ (because $\sup_n \|u_n\|_{W^{k,p}} =1$ as we normalized each of them), therefore by compact inclusion there is a convergent subsequence $u_{n_j} \xrightarrow{W^{|\alpha|,p}} u$.

Now, write down the contradictory statement :
$$
\|D^{\alpha} u_{n_j}\|_{L^p} > \epsilon\|u_{n_j}\|_{W^{k,p}} + n \|u_{n_j}\|_{L^p} = \epsilon + n \|u_{n_j}\|_{L^p} \tag{*}
$$

Note that since $1 = \|u_{n_j}\|_{W^{k,p}} \geq \|D^{\alpha}u_{n_j}\|_{L^p}$, the LHS is bounded by $1$. From here, the right hand side must be bounded by $1$. But for that to occur, we must have $\|u\|_{L^p} = 0$, since if not , then the RHS will look like $\epsilon + n \|u\|_{L^p}$ for large $n$, which is not bounded unless $\|u\|_{L^p} = 0$. Hence $u=0$.

But we also have $D^{\alpha} u_{n_j} \xrightarrow{L^p} D^{\alpha} u = 0$. However, if we take limits in $*$ we get $\|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^p} > \epsilon$. This completes the contradiction.

Comment: Thank you!! I was stuck in the $D^\alpha u_{n_j}.$